# How to press RET to insert a newline while remaining in "normal" evil mode?

Tags: evil

I want to insert a newline by pressing the return key, but keep the normal status in evil mode. In Vim, I can do this by `nmap <CR> o<Esc>`. What is its equivalent in evil-mode?

Answer (score 3):

I unbind `RET`, `SPC` and `TAB` (this one might be controversial) in normal state.  This isn't strictly the equivalent, but works well for me:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "RET") nil)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "TAB") nil))
```

Comment: I only  take what I want: `(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "RET") nil))` and it works.  Many thanks.

Comment: @harryln : if this solution works for you, please upvote and accept the answer.